# erro ao executar view asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Ao rodar o projeto e chamar a *view* está me retornando o seguinte erro:

```
The view at '~/Views/Produto/List.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>.
```

Código da View:

```
@using Domain.Entidades
@model IEnumerable<Produto>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Produtos";
}
@foreach(var p in Model)
{
    <div>
        <h3>@p.Nome</h3>
        @p.Descricao
        <h4>@p.Price.ToString("c")</h4>
    </div>
}
```

Como resolver?

Comment: Poste o código da view

Comment: Posta o código do arquivo List.cshtml

Comment: adicionei o código na pergunta

Comment: Como está o arquivo `Web.config` do diretório `Views`?